# How to iterate a list in Firebase Security Rules language?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I have the following condition written in Firebase Storage Rules:

```js
allow read: if resource.metadata.company.includes(request.auth.uid);
```

This returns the following error:

> Error running simulation – Error: simulator.rules line [9], column [22]. Function not found error: Name: [includes].

What I want to do is to iterate through a list and check if an object exists in that list; something that resembles `includes()`. How to do that in Firebase Security Rules Language?

**NOTE:** *Already tried for loops and they don't work.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution for it by using `string.matches('.*'+resource.metadata.company+'.*')`. Why am I using `matches`? That is because my array is a JSON string. Hope this helps other people.

Check documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.String#matches

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a given field of type `string` is equal to any value from a `list`

```
function isAnyOf(input, allowedValues) {
  return input is string && 
    input in allowedValues;
}

allow read: if isAnyOf(resource.metadata.company, [request.auth.uid]);
```

Or if company field is a `list|array` then you can use

```
allow read: if request.resource.data.company.hasAny([request.auth.uid])
```

For reference here some further readin:

- https://firebase.blog/posts/2020/06/new-firestore-security-rules-features